# unable to modify user table search results based on meta key

Tags: wp-user-query

I would like to modify the `pre_user-query` `wp_user_query` to include a meta fields from the user meta.

I have tried the two following methods, neither of which work (both return empty sets):

```
$query->query_from .= "  LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_usermeta AS alias ON (wp_users.ID = alias.user_id)";`

$query->query_where = str_replace(')', " OR alias.meta_value LIKE '%CH60 6RR%' )",$query->query_where);`
```

and

```
  $query->meta_query =  array('relation' => 'OR', 'compare' => 'LIKE', array( 'meta_key'  => 'billing_postcode', 'meta_value' => 'CH60 6RR'));
```

Could someone explain the correct way to return the results?

Comment: The second variant goes into the action pre_get_users (and is the cleaner way imho), but it's key instead of Meta_key, and value instead of Meta_value iirc.

Comment: And the `compare` should be inside the the nested array of the `key` and `value`

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers : Do you know why the first two queries are not working?

Comment: OK this method is working : `function custom_user_search($query) { $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'billing_postcode'; $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = 'CH60 6RR';  print_r($query);}`

Comment: Is possible to add multiple keys?